# Smarty variable problem

Tags: php, smarty

Hey, ive a problem with my assigned variable in smarty. 
I want to assigns some values to an other template, but it doesn't work correctly. The problematic line is here:

```
{{include file="lib/topmenu_item.tpl" onclick="load_from_php('pageBody', '{{$base_url}}index.php/datasources/grouping', 'grouping', this);" node="datasources/grouping" text="Grouping"}}
```

i want to add the value of the $base_url to the front of the url. How can i do that?

Ps: {{ and }} are my delimiters

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
{{include file="lib/topmenu_item.tpl" onclick="load_from_php('pageBody', '{{' . $base_url. '}}index.php/datasources/grouping', 'grouping', this);" node="datasources/grouping" text="Grouping"}}
```

Use string concatenation to use the variabele in your string.

Comment: Aah, this would be so trivial under normal conditions :D Thanks!